# Redirect user back to script after closing text editor

Tags: bash

Writing a script that opens a text file in nano for a user to edit. After the user has finished editing the file I want to return to the script.

How could I detect the user exiting the text editor without exiting the running script?

Here is the current code I have:

```
!#/bin/bash

if [[ "$displaytext" == "y" ]]; then

    read -p "Would You Like To Remove Text From File?: y/n " remove

    if [[ "$remove" == "y" ]]; then
        "${EDITOR:-nano}" File.txt
    fi

fi
```

Comment: The only reason the user is going out to the prompt after the editor is closed is because _there's nothing else in your script after that point_. If there was anything else in the script, the user would be seeing it. As such, there's not a problem here that we can help to solve: The user isn't seeing any further output from or interactions with your script only because there's nothing else to see.

Comment: Oh, I assumed it was exiting automatically. Well cheers mate, appreciate the response